# Where is jQuery UI 1.8.20?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-autocomplete

I use the jQuery UI 1.10.4 autocomplete plugin in an ASP.NET MVC 4 application.
When I run the app it gives this message:

**TypeError: this.element.propAttr is not a function** in jquery-ui.1.8.20.js

I do not understand this error because there in not this version of jQuery in the Scripts folder.
What causes this error, please?

Comment: Have you checked if a page is including it from an external location?

Comment: But do you have that version of jQuery UI? It's not the same as jQuery.

Comment: No, it is not inclided from external location. There is not any reference to external file. I use jquery-1.11.1.js ("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js") and jquery-ui-1.10.4.js. ("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js").

Comment: When I have turned on the Show All option the jquery-ui-1.8.20.js showed up. Thank you for replies. :)